# Can't get rid of sections background color in grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have been trying to create a grouped UItableView with clear background. But for some reason the sections still have light gray color. I tried to set backgroundview to nil which didn't work. I also tried to set backgroundView to a view with clearColor and didn't work either. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
// make table's background clear
[self.myTable setBackgroundView:nil];
[self.myTable setBackgroundView:[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]];

UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.myTable.frame];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.myTable.backgroundView = bgView;
[bgView release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make the cell's background clear you need to change the **backgroundView** property of the UICellView to an actual view (nil doesn't work), in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

add this

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Which will create a blank/empty backgroundView for the cells

Comment: Thanks, I had set cells background color to clear but looks like your answer did what I wanted. Thanks